# Deprecation Warning while installing wheel for scikit-learn

Tags: python, deprecation-warning

I am new to Python. Can someone tell me how should I solve this error.

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Hiwi\Python Programs>py TSP.py
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\six.py:28: DeprecationWarning: The module is deprecated in version 0.21 and will be removed in version 0.23 since we've dropped support for Python 2.7. Please rely on the official version of six (https://pypi.org/project/six/).
  warnings.warn("The module is deprecated in version 0.21 and will be removed "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TSP.py", line 4, in <module>
    fitness_coords = mlrose.TravellingSales(coords=coords_lists)
NameError: name 'coords_lists' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not an error, so there's nothing to solve exactly. It's warning you that you're using an unsupported version of Python (2.7) and should probably upgrade, otherwise you _might_ run into problems. [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) states on PyPI that it requires python 3.5+.

Comment: It's not an error yet, just a warning that when version 0.23 of the library comes out the module will be deprecated. Python has been running parallel versions 2 and 3 because some things in version 3 are not backward compatible with version 2.  Python 2 support will end at the end of 2019, so it's a good time to switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

or running with:

```
python3 -W ignore::DeprecationWarning -W ignore::PendingDeprecationWarning program.py
```

help?

Also you can try:

```
import warnings 
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=PendingDeprecationWarning) 
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

If you post an example of the exact code that leads to the error, I can further update my answer for your exact case. One of the two above warnings.simplefilters should ignore it for you. I've tested it  from collections import Hashable and it works, but i'm not sure what import your using, but give it a try, it should work

UPDATE: It looks like you have two things going on, one is the warning and the second is the error. With the error it just seems like you missing the coords_list variable

Comment: No I copied both of them, unfortuately it didn' work for me. Here is the entire message that I am getting. I have edited the body of my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an error just a `warning`. Next, it seems from `py TSP.py` that you are actually trying to run a python script.

In the 4th line `fitness_coords = mlrose.TravellingSales(coords=coords_lists)` it seems that `coords_lists` is not defined before.

Are you trying to run [this](https://share.cocalc.com/share/c751c941cb6cc4161c8232d83b41a502e0b7765e/py3-mlrose.ipynb?viewer=share) ???

Then you need to have in the `TSP.py` file something like this:

```
# Create list of city coordinates
coords_list = [(1, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 4), (4, 4), (3, 6), (1, 5), (2, 3)]

# Initialize fitness function object using coords_list
fitness_coords = mlrose.TravellingSales(coords = coords_list)
```

---

For the warning use this **inside** the **.py** file:

```
import something

def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i get rid of the warning?